# Объяснение работы test and set

Tags: ассемблер

Читаю про команду [test-and-set](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) на вики.

Возможно вопрос совсем глупый, но мне непонятны уже первые 2 строки:

```
  enter_critical_section:
  TSL REGISTER, LOCK // Значение переменной LOCK копируется в регистр
                        // и устанавливается в 1.
     CMP REGISTER, #0   // Старое значение сравнивается с нулем.
     JNE enter_critical_section // Если оно ненулевое, значит кто-то уже вошел в критическую секцию и заблокировал её.
```

Если значение LOCK копируется в регистр в первой строке, то как во второй строке в REGISTER может находиться старое значение (ведь мы туда только что LOCK записали)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TSL

- копирует **старое** значение переменной LOCK в регистр.
- и сразу же **после** этого выставляет переменную LOCK в 1.

Т.е. она "выхватывает" старое значение из LOCK, причем атомарно - т.е. только один поток выхватить оттуда 0. И можно считать что тот, кто поймал 0 - тот и владеет теперь блокировкой.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение :)